# Convert yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ date format in mmm dd hh:mm using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I receive from a WebService a string with a date in this format 
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ. I need to convert it in a format like mmm dd hh mm using JavaScript. For example change the string "2017-02-08T09:19:47.550Z" to Feb 08 09:19.

How do I achieve this??

Comment: `var d = new Date("2017-02-08T09:19:47.550Z")` ... now `d` is a date object with [date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you can use to make your output

Comment: Which date method would be appropriate here??

Comment: getDate, getMonth, getHours ... and maybe one more - can you guess, is it getYear? or maybe getSeconds? no, neither of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While usually people do use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for complex date manipulation, this problem can be solved quite trivially with vanilla JS string manipulation and the [`Date#toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) method.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var utc = date.toUTCString() // 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss GMT'
  return utc.slice(8, 12) + utc.slice(5, 8) + utc.slice(17, 22)
}

console.log(
  formatDate(new Date('2017-02-08T09:19:47.550Z'))
) //=> 'Feb 08 09:19'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some external library like moment.js https://momentjs.com/

This will do the conversion for you

Answer (score 0):

Usually people use moment:

```
moment(dateFromBackend, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ').format('MMM DD HH:mm')
```

Formating options are available [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)